How to avoid scrolling issue when using React Select with Dialog?
There is a scrolling problem when Select (React Select) is used in Dialog (Mui Dialog). Scrolling is required within the modal.

As seen in the pictures, when I use Mui Select, the modal is used without causing problems by overflowing. How can I do this with React select?

zIndex values ​​were given to the styles property of React select, but it did not work.
container: (baseStyles: any) => ({
...baseStyles,
zIndex: 9999
}),
menu: (baseStyles: any) => ({
...baseStyles,
zIndex: 9999
}),


Not sure how to fix your issue. Leaving my Codesandbox which  reproduces your issue. I would try to scroll the menu into view but I haven't found a fix yet,

Did you try giving that telephone country code field a maximum height so that it doesn't overflow?
